# Hölder Continuity in Time for the Solution of the Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, holder-spaces

I am looking for estimates of the Hölder norm for the time-variable of the solution of the heat equation. Let me formulate the problem:

Consider the problem

$\partial_t u(t,x) = \partial_x^2 u(t,x)$, $(t,x) \in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$

with initial condition

$u(0,x)=u^0(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

where $u^0\in C^{1,\alpha} (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $u^0$ is continuously differentiable and the derivative is (locally) $\alpha$-Hölder continuous ($\alpha$-Hölder continuous on $[-a,a]$, with a Hölder constant depending on $a\in \mathbb{R}$).

Then, the solution is given by $P_t u^0(x)$, where $(P_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ denotes the heat semigroup.

I want an estimate for

$\left |P_t u^0(x) - u^0(x)\right |$, $x\in [-a,a]$,

in terms of the $\alpha$-Hölder norm of the derivative of $u^0$ on $[-a,a]$.

Do you know such a result or a similar result, or do you have an idea where I could find it?

Thank you for your help!
Luke

Comment: In general, the t-regularity of a solution of the heat equation is "half" the x-regularity. Therefore you should expect that $|P_t u_0(x) - u_0(x)| = O(t^\beta)$ for all $\beta  < \frac{1+\alpha}{2}$ in this situation.

Comment: I have read this rule of thumb that the time regularity is half the space regularity a couple times, but I have never seen a rigorous statement or proof of it. Do you have a literature recommendation for that?

Comment: You could look in Friedman's book on parabolic equations, which has "subelliptic" estimates of this nature.